# Set up value of UITextField before loading view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Say I have a class1 and it has a view with a UITextField and a save button that saves the text of the field in an array. Now I also have a class2. In this class2, I want to load the class1 view with the tap of a button. However, I went to set the value of the UITextField before I show this view, so that when class1 appears the UITextField already has a string in it and is editable with a tap. Is this possible?

Edit: Only class2 knows what the textfield value will be

Edit: I tried this

```
    [newInkView setInkTextField:[appDelegate.inks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSLog([appDelegate.inks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
    [self.view addSubview:newInkView.view];
    [self presentModalViewController:newInkView animated:YES];
```

but this wasn't able to set the text field value. The NSLog did display some value though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>To get the text sent from the class you can do something like this in class1:</strike>

```
-(void)setTextString:(NSString*)value
{
yourField.text = value;
}
```

As long as you call it before you show the view it'll be there when the view is loaded, granted you have an instance of class1 in class2.

Edit:

This was fixed by using NSUserDefaults to save the string before the view was loaded and load it when it was loaded.

Comment: But only class2 knows what the text value will be

Comment: Then create a method that passes it along.  See my answer for an example.

Comment: Sorry I meant only class2 knows what it will be

Comment: I tried this:`[newInkView setInkTextField:[appDelegate.inks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSLog([appDelegate.inks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
    [self.view addSubview:newInkView.view];
    [self presentModalViewController:newInkView animated:YES];` but when the view loads the text field is empty however the log does display text. What can the problem be?

Comment: try putting the set text field after you add the subview.  Your users really wouldn't notice it.  If that doesn't work, you could use NSUserDefaults to store the text and read it in your `viewWillAppear` method

Comment: No this didn't work. And it's not about remembering the value. It's because class2 has an array and knows the index value..

Comment: @MattS. let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2679/discussion-between-fprime-and-matt-s)

Answer (score 0):

Why not set a property of your view controller with the value and have the VC copy the value to the text field in viewWillAppear??